# Add two elements at a time, one inside the other, to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a proxy application retrieving 'src' attributes cross domain from an xml list of photos.

I want to append images full size INSIDE of presized div's so they render in a uniform size, without stretching.

I know how to append the images on their own, but I don't know how to create a div, append the image to that element, then appendTo that div with the img to a container.

tl;dr;
Right now I have this

```
$("<img>").attr("src", stuff).attr('class','imgur').appendTo("#content");
```

Producing this:

```
<div id="content">
  <img />
  <img />
  <img />
  <img />
</div>
```

And I want this:

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="window"><img /></div>
  <div class="window"><img /></div>
  <div class="window"><img /></div>
  <div class="window"><img /></div>
</div>
```

***Answer slightly modified to meet my use case:***

```
function imgAdd(param) {
    var content = document.getElementById("content");
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = param;
    img.classList.add("imgur");
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add("window");
    div.appendChild(img);
    content.appendChild(div);
  }
```

Being fired by:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("imgAdd", p.src);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var content = document.getElementById("content");
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = data[i].stuff;
  img.classList.add("imgur");
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.classList.add("window");
  div.appendChild(img);
  content.appendChild(div);
}
```

May require a [classList shim](https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js) or a [DOM shim](https://github.com/Raynos/DOM-shim) for legacy platform support.

If you don't want a classList shim you can manipulate `.className` directly.

`.className = "string"` or `.className += " string"`

Comment: This works best. The images are added one at a time every 20 milliseconds for nice presentation. I can wrap this in a function that takes a string for src, and call it every 20 ms, excluding the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following

```
var theDiv = $('<div></div>');
$('<img>').attr('src', stuff).attr('class', 'imgur').appendTo(theDiv);
theDiv.appendTo('#content');
```

Comment: I'd switch the last two lines, so that only one reflow occurs.

Comment: @RobW Done.  By 'reflow' do you mean limiting the number of times the HTML page needs to perform a layout?

Comment: @RobW that's what I thought. Just wanted to verify

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#content').append('<div class="window"><img /></div>');
```

But if you only need images to have uniform sizes, CSS is the way to go.

Comment: But then you have inline HTML, breaking separations of concerns. This is a bad practice.

Comment: Depends what he needs, really. He could make a nice little function with src parameter and improve the code a lot. I only gave an idea. Your code is good for adding many images with the same src, which I doubt he needs.